# How to remove the time duration when the notification started on the notification of an android foreground service?

Tags: notifications, foreground-service, android-8.1-oreo

[Here is the notification with the highlighted duration(2m) when the notification started.I don not want to display it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfLbq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
.setContentTitle("My notification")
.setContentText("Hello World!")
.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
.setWhen(0);
```

setWhen(0) makes the time duration in the notification empty.